# Can't change keep-alive header of ngrok's request and response

Tags: node.js, ssl, ngrok

I have exposed my localhost via NGROK , but one of my request takes long time to respond , but after 5 minutes of no response from my local server , NGROK disconnects the open connection with client, and client here receives an error as : Socket Hang Up OR some times postman crashes. But the server never encountered any error. This error is from ngrok side which keeps the header "keep-alive:5", and client got error on extact 5 minutes.

[image: This error is caught in case postman is not crashed]

The crashing error might be as I also encountered it before :

20168:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:

I tried to change this header with commands

./ngrok http --request-header-add "Keep-Alive: timeout=60"  --response-header-add "Keep-Alive: timeout=60" 3001

but nothing changes, ngrok still uses same config as its req, res headers.

[image: These are the headers after running the above command]

Stuck on this , any kind of help is really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are running into the wrong direction with your question. The keep-alive header is totally unrelated to the timeout of a request. It is only relevant for the time between a finished response and the next request coming in. So changing the header will not fix your problem.

Comment: Does this request always take time to respond even if you do not use ngrok? If so you can try with some other tunnelling tool like https://pinggy.io

Comment: @BishakhGhosh ,hey if i run this locally on local host. It runs fine request takes time but never got any error , i tried different tunneling services like localtunnel, localtonet , they returns a gateway timeout error after a fixed time , so i suppose ngrok is also behaving something same ., I will try pinggy.io thanks